# How to access child div of a div which do not have ID

Tags: jquery

```
<div name='hello'>

    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>

</div>
```

I want to access the div having 1 and change its content.Using J query

I tried something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[name="Hello"]').find('div :first-child').text('One');   
});
```

Comment: Check your name-attribute, you have "hello" in small letters and the selector you are using has capital H.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a space away

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[name="hello"]').find('div:first-child').text('One');   
//                                 ^^ remove space
});
```

And names are case sensitive

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ6Nq/)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `find`

```
$('div[name="Hello"] div:first-child').text('One');
```

Comment: The problem was with the extra space, not with `find`. In fact, the `find` version is more efficient

Comment: How is it more efficient?

Comment: *The `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements*. Well, basically jQuery will have to parse your selector, determine that it must search for a `div` with name *Hello*, then it would have to determine based on the white space that you want to further do a `find()` on its children. 
By directly calling `find()` you skip further computation on the selector (which should be kept as simple as possible).

Answer (score 1):

You were just using an extra space

```
$('div[name="hello"]').find('div :first-child').text('One');
```

Replace that and write the code as:

```
$('div[name="hello"]').find('div:first-child').text('One');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

Using `:contains()` in a context:

```
$('div:contains("1")', 'div[name="hello"]').text('One');
```

[**Checkout the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pGbqc/)

and you can try with `:contains()` and `.find()` methods too:

```
$('div[name="hello"]').find('div:contains("1")').text('One');
```

#### Note:

`name='hello' !== name='Hello'` it means this is case sensitive. you have used name in all lowercase and in your selector context you have used an uppercase `"H"` which is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $($('div[name="hello"]').children()[0]).text('One');   
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[name="hello"]>:first-child').text('One');
    $('div[name="hello"]>:first-child').next().next().text('Three');   
});
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

you have to give id for your child divs..
1st div of child id=mainContainer

1
    2
    3
    4
    5

$("#mainContainer :first-child").attr('id')